# How can i reduce the PDF File Size while Uploading time in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, size, reduce

Can any one please help me for
How to reduce the PDF File Size while Uploading time in C#
image compression done my side but iam unable to compress the pdf file
I tried to uploading pdf file but i want to compress that before uploading

Comment: Please try to add a [mre] so we can see what you are trying to achieve. In this state your question is to broad. Try to take the [tour] and read [ask].